# How to remove excess glue from around the edges of paper?

Tags: paper, tool-selection, adhesives

To make a post card, I like to stick small pieces of paper on a card. I put glue stick on the whole paper, because if the corners don't have enough glue, it will not be strong enough. However, when I stick the paper on the card, often some glue comes from beneath on the card.

What tool can be used to remove glue stick?

I have seen people use a cotton tissue, a toothpick or a craft knife. What are pros and cons?

Comment: Are you saying that when you press the paper to the card it squeezes glue out from the edges, and some of that gets into the surface of the card, where it doesn't belong? You just need to clean the finished sides? What type of paper are you using?

Comment: @CreationEdge exactly. Feel free to edit, English is not my mother tongue. I'm using 165g paper.

Comment: For the paper, is it gloss or matte?

Comment: @CreationEdge matte, and sometimes slightly textured.

Comment: I've used craft sticks (aka wooden popsicle sticks) to smooth the surface and then scrape away the excess for this sort of thing before ... I don't know it compares to the others, though.

Comment: This actually sounds like it would be ideal for an experiment answer -- somebody try all the options! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cotton tissue**: I find this to be the most messy option, since it's difficult to regulate where the glue ends up, which means you might get glue on places where you do not want it

**a toothpick**: The sharp point might damage your paper if you press too hard

**craft knife**: might make your knife dull!

I mostly use thick scrap paper (or craft sticks) to scrape the glue off and haven't had any problems with that.

Comment: I also use thick scrap paper. It's cheap, you can cut it into any shape you want (say, if you need more precision, you cut it to an acute angle), and if your edge is flat, it easily scrapes the glue bits away.

Answer (score -1):

Adhesive pick-up squares are great tool for maintaining a perfect effect. I used them a lot during my art school years. They cost around a $1-2 USD, so they're very cheap. You can find them in most art supply stores.

Comment: I think that that would create too much distance between the layers, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

If your paper is thick enough, you can water down liquid glue and spread it with a brush.  That's worked for me.

Comment: I don't think covering the whole card solves OP's question of *How to remove excess glue at the edges?* at all.

Comment: Agree with @Stephie -- this sounds like a very good method to _avoid_ having excess glue at edges, but that's not exactly the OP's situation.